# how to deploy a Ruby on Rails website. there is MongoDB as database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, mongodb

please give specific steps. also mention requirements on the server. (right now i only want to test my website on a particular host)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way would be using [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com), which is highly recommended if you don't know anything about administering a system.  Another easy way, would be using Phusion Passenger with Apache.

See these resources to get you started:
[Phusion Passenger Web site](http://www.modrails.com)
[Phusion Passenger Install Guide](http://www.modrails.com/install.html)
[Apache + Phusion Passenger Tutorial, using Ubuntu](http://wdvl.com/Authoring/ror/Passenger/saurabh_bhatia04142010.html)
[Another Phusion Passenger installation tutorial, using CentOS](http://ashleyangell.com/2010/02/how-to-install-phusion-passenger-on-a-centoscpanel-box/)
[MongoDB Website](http://www.mongodb.org/)
[MongoDB Unix Installation Guide](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Unix)

However, I highly, *highly* recommend you to use [Heroku](https://mongohq.com/home) with [MongoHQ](https://mongohq.com/home).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Heroku.com](http://heroku.com)